# jQuery list quantity not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery and coding in general. After several days being dragged in the mud making a shopping list App in jQuery I've made a lot of progress, but I'm struggling with 2 things.

My quantity selector was implemented but once my number quantity is selected and added, it wont show up on my list. I'm having a hard time seeing what and where I'm missing the proper string to make the quantity show up in list when the add button is clicked.

**Heres my code Demo**: http://jsbin.com/cetisobuhe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the second `<input />`'s value:

```
var new_task = $('input').val() + ": " + $('input + input').val();
```

In your current implementation, which is kinda wrong, the above code works. See this:

[image]

**Output: http://output.jsbin.com/negiguhumu/1**

---

**Better Version**

Instead of using something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="new-text" placeholder="Add item to list"/>
<input type="number">
```

```
var new_task = $('input').val() + ": " + $('input + input').val();
```

It is better to use:

```
<input type="text" id="new-text" placeholder="Add item to list" />
<input type="number" id="quantity" />
```

```
var new_task = $('#new-text').val() + ": " + $('#quantity').val();
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help. 

You mentioned my current implementation is kinda wrong. Is there a better way to go about this kind of list that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @ThomasT. Yes, please use `id="name"` and `id="qty"` or something and access that way.

Comment: @ThomasT. Do you want me to give an example or is it okay?

Comment: @ThomasT. Check the updated answer boss. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for all your insight! It's very appreciated. This has been killing me for days now! haha Thank you!!

Comment: @ThomasT. All the best buddy.